# Handle Google Firestore Javascript date fields with Redux

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data from Google Firestore database and storing it in redux to display in React app. I've noticed that any timestamp fields returned by Firestore Javascript API are not represented as Datetime but rather as `{seconds: 1682801225, nanoseconds: 482000000}` structure.

I'm trying to understand how it best to handle them giving that this is not just an object with those fields it also has functions from its prototype.

Should I transform/sanitize any response from Firestore to objects that I would like to use in Redux? In this case transform most fields as-is and the timestamp field to regular Date?

Answer (score 0):

What is best is highly dependent on your use-case, but the two most common approach are:

- Convert the [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp) that you get back from Firestore to a JavaScript `Date` object right away by calling [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp#timestamptodate) on it.
- Pass the `Timestamp` object that you get back from Firestore around until you need to display it, and *then* convert it to a date.